# All internal drives are showing as removable, but actual removable drives no longer auto-mount

Tags: 20.04, automount, drive

I'm running 20.04.  Recently I've noticed that all of the entries I have in fstab are now showing up as removable devices in Nemo, although if I try and eject them it fails because I am not root.

At the same time, if I plug in any flash drive, it does not pop up in my removable drives list in the systray asking if I want to mount it.  I've verified in syslog that the drive is recognized and there are no problems.  I can manually mount it from the command line.  I've tested several different flash drives with varying filesystems, all with the same result.

I'm assuming these two issues are related, but I haven't found any reason for it yet.  I'm using Cinnamon, but I've confirmed that the same issue exists in Plasma.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  The udisks2.service was masked.  I had to run systemctl unmask udisks2.service and then systemctl enable udisks2.service.  After a reboot both problems were solved.